# What is Dem Operation Cycle in AUTOSAR?

Tags: diagnostics, autosar

I am learning AUTOSAR module Dem. I am going through specification document of Dem module. I wanted to know what is Operation cycle in Dem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intention is to let you define several different operation cycles because you may have different ways of handling certain diagnostic information in different cycles.

The most typical cycle would be to have an ignition cycle and a driving cycle. That way you could have different logic for some DTCs when the ignition is on but the engine hasn't yet started, and for when the engine is up. You can also have time-based operation cycles, which restart every X minutes.